# Windows - Apache DocumentRoot in VirtualHost ignored

Tags: windows, apache, xampp, httpd.conf, vhosts

On my Windows 7 PC, I'm using XAMPP => Apache to run a testing webserver. But for a certain website I don't want the regular "C:\xampp\htdocs", but a custom path - which when I work on Ubuntu I usually setup in VirtualHost just as a `DocumentRoot` and it works.

On this PC the target path is similar to: 
`"C:\Users\X\Disk External\DIRWITHDIÁCRÍCÍCS\WEBS\some path\path"`

However on this PC when I do

```
<VirtualHost test2020.test:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\X\Disk External\DIRWITHDIÁCRÍCÍCS\WEBS\some path\path"
    ServerName test2020.test
    ServerAlias www.test2020.test
</VirtualHost>
```

**The DocumentRoot directive is completely ignored** - it still seems to target files in the default `C:\xampp\htdocs`

I've also tried moving the files around the system and changing forward/backward slashes with no success:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/Users/X/Disk External/DIRWITHDIÁCRÍCÍCS/WEBS/some path/path"
DocumentRoot C:\xampp\htdocs\testdocumentroot
DocumentRoot "C:\Users\X\www"
```

Also I've tried swapping order of DocumentRoot and ServerName with no success.

I've checked C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf - the line `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` IS uncommented.

And the file `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` seems to affect apache start-up when set-up wrongly.

EDIT: also I did restart apache between each try :)

What am I missing?

Comment: Should this question be moved to a different stackexchange site? (SO is full of apache/virtualhost questions)

Answer (score 0):

So it's just my idiotism, I've tried to overdomain everything, but the directive **attribute** inside the VirtualHost tag is for network incoming limitation. For regular cases `*` is just fine there, also then I had a problem with Directory tag directive because aparently there's a new directive for [Apache 2.4+](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html)

<s>`<VirtualHost test2020.test:443>`</s> => `<VirtualHost *:443>`

#### Working final code:

```
# (or *:80 for http:// , 443 is for https://)
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Users\X\Disk External\DIRWITHDIÁCRÍCÍCS\WEBS\some path\path"
    ServerName test2020.test
    ServerAlias www.test2020.test
   
    <Directory "C:\Users\X\Disk External\DIRWITHDIÁCRÍCÍCS\WEBS\some path\path">
        # NEW&SIMPLE FROM APACHE 2.4+ !
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```